# If $R/P$ is an integral domain then $P\vartriangleleft R$ is prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification

Let $R$ be a ring and let $P$ be a proper ideal of $R$.

If the quotient ring, $R/P$ is an integral domain then $P\vartriangleleft R$ is prime.

For $x,y\in R$ we have $(x+P)(y+P)=xy+P\in P\vartriangleleft R$, and since $P\vartriangleleft R$ is an integral domain $x,y\neq 0$.

Also, we have that $R$ and $P\vartriangleleft R$ are rings, so there exists a zero element such that $$(x+P)(y+P)=xy+P=0_R+P=(0_R+P)(0_R+P).$$

Since $x,y$ are nonzero this is possible only if $x\in P$ or $y\in P$.

Therefore $P\vartriangleleft R$ is prime by definition.

Is my proof correct? I would appreciate any help/hint.

Comment: @DietrichBurde This is a *different* attempt at a proof.

Comment: Do you mean to write $P \triangleleft R$ instead of $R \triangleleft P$?  Also, $xy + P \notin R$.  Elements of $P$ and $R$ are elements of the ring.  The notation $xy + P$ denotes an equivalence class.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 Yes, sorry. I have corrected the typo. In my proof I mean $xy+P$ in the quotient ring $P\vartriangleleft R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your proof is incorrect.

You should start with $x,y\in R$ such that $xy\in P$ (and you wish to prove that either $x\in P$ or $y\in P$).

Since $xy\in P$, we have, in $R/P$,
$$
0+P=xy+P=(x+P)(y+P)
$$
and, since $R/P$ is an integral domain, either $x+P=0+P$ or $y+P=0+P$. In other words, either $x\in P$ or $y\in P$.

Comment: I think I am doing the same thing but I just did not write explicitly "such that"; implicitly I assume that $xy\in P$. Is that a serious mistake?

Comment: @johnny09 Yes, I'm afraid.